# Are there any ebook readers in Ubuntu that support middle button scrolling?

Tags: mouse, pdf, ebooks

I recently shifted all work to Ubuntu, but to my endless frustration I could not find an ebook readers that allow middle button scrolling (Click and drag using the mouse wheel) or any variation of it. As someone who uses a large number of 1000+ pages documents for work, this has made my life miserable.

Are there any ebook readers that permit this on Ubuntu? Or am I forced to stick to browser builtin readers for now?

Comment: Did you try `Calibre`? It has middle-button scrolling. Scrolling/page flipping options are configurable.

Comment: Yes, somehow it opens in the default reader (Evince). Does it have a built in reader (sorry I am not that familiar with Calibre)? I could not find any configuration settings for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Calibre` is an e book reader.

You can change the default application to `Calibre` for a file type with these instructions: [Change Default Applications](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/06/change-default-applications-on-ubuntu-1804.html?m=1)

Install `calibre` using Software or `sudo apt-get install calibre`  if you like the terminal.